# DataGridViewButtonColumn text updation during run-time

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a `DataGridView` in which I have one `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. I have provided default text for `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.

On click of `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, text should gets updated with some different text for that particular cell not for the whole column.

How to update the text value for `DataGridViewButtonColumn` for one cell during run-time ?

```
private void StructDataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "C")
            {
                DataGridViewCell butC = (DataGridViewCell)senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6];
                butC.Value = "N";                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why your current solution not working?

Comment: With the current solution 'DataGridViewButtonColumn' Text value is not getting updated.